# Windows 10 Search is not working, can't even type the query

Tags: windows, search

My problem is that Windows' Start menu search isn't working at all, when I press Start then start typing, nothing happens, the same thing also happen in taskbar search box and search icon. Cortana icon works, but since it is not available in my country it only display this 'unavailable' message. This has been going for the last 2-3 months since Windows 2004 is available, I installed fresh from ISO. My current Windows 10 is fully updated, and I didn't touch registry or group policy editor at all.

Things I have tried:

1. [ResetWindowsSearchbox powershell script](https://superuser.com/questions/1129353/windows-10-search-not-working-searchui-exe-missing), after restart, search is still not working
2. [Installing Cortana from PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1002335/windows-10-search-is-not-working-properly), the command simply does nothing and outputs nothing, tried in administrator and normal PowerShell, tried copy pasting and typing by letter, same results.
3. Run search troubleshooting from Settings app, also rebuilding index
4. Creating a new user account, on the new user account search works, but eventually it will stop working again in a few days or weeks. Moving user account is a lot of hassle and is not a permanent solution.
5. Reinstalling Windows obviously make it work again, but same as point 4, the problem will eventually arise and I had to create new user/reinstall Windows.

Is there a permanent fix for this? Or a solution where I don't have to constantly do everything from scratch again?

Comment: If you have installed Windows 10 fresh, and Search stops working, the only thing I can imagine is legacy software of some kind that interferes. I have Search working here  for the 4 years I have had the machine.

Comment: That's my assumption as well, since my previous PC last years with exact same software as my current one. But I don't think it's the case, since if I created a new user account, with exact same installed programs, as they are installed in Program Files, then the new user account has search working.. for a while, might take days or weeks but it is certain, as I have said in my original post.

Comment: If you are willing, try a new install, newest version of Office 365, newest version of Adobe, set up Search and it should be fine.

Comment: Yes it will be fine, as I have stated. My question is more about how to fix this problem, preferably permanently, without starting fresh, and without creating new user, as I have lived with this workaround for months.

Comment: Search works perfectly on Windows 10 with modern software.

Comment: Yeah.. that give me an idea though. I'll leave my problematic user account intact, create a new one, again (for the fourth time *sigh*), then create another user account which I will install the software one by one periodically. Maybe I can determine what causes the issue.

Comment: Just for future reference, the culprit is Microsoft Edge. It is stuck installing/downloading/updating/whateveritsdoing. On the app list there is this gray progress bar that won't go away. On a new user account, Edge works, but whenever it is running, Windows search is not working, closed it and search works again. This might be why search will eventually broken again, since Edge will again become stuck on updating whenever there is any patch for it through Windows Update every month.

Comment: I concur with @Nur, using a **different** user account on the **same** PC works so that rules out _"legacy software"_

Comment: What do you mean by _"On the app list there is this gray progress bar that won't go away"_?  Task Manager? What tab?

Comment: @Nur I seem to have the same problem you had. I documented all the stuff I tried to fix it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1766410/windows-search-broken-and-no-fix-has-worked-yet-what-more-can-i-do-onenote-an) but didn't have any luck yet. Did you manage to fix it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
Open Win 10 registry and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TimeBrokerSvc

On the right panel double click on start and verify if the value is set to 3 in hex. if not set it to 3 and restart your computer and see if it fix the problem.